# How do I create a new array from 2 existing arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a new array from 2 already existing arrays. The array I need to create will grab a value from each existing array and match them accordingly.

Example of Array 1:

```
0: "110235"
1: "110236"
2: "345272663"
3: "345269790"
4: "110533"
```

Example of Array 2:

```
0: true
1: true
2: false
3: true
4: false
```

Desired New Array:

```
0: value1: "110235", value2: true
1: value1: "110236", value2: true
2: value1: "345272663", value2: false
3: value1: "345269790", value2: true
4: value1: "110533", value2: false
```

Here is the code I am using to currently generate both existing arrays.

```
$(".save-button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var inputValue = $(".checkbox-input").map(function(){
          return $(this).prop( "checked" )
        }).get(); 
        var subscriptionId = $(".checkbox-input").map(function(){
            return $(this).closest('.subscription').attr('data-subscription-id');
          }).get();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes that both of the constituent arrays have the same length.

```
var array1 = ["110235", ...];
var array2 = [true, ...];
var targetArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    targetArray.push({value1: array1[i], value2: array2[i]});
}
```

If they don't have the same length, then it depends on how you want to handle values that can't be matched to the other array. You could either limit `targetArray` to the minimum of the lengths of the constituent arrays, or you could assume null when arrays are too short.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single `$(".checkbox-input").map`, then just do both parts of your value building in the single map.

```
var desiredNewArray = $(".checkbox-input").map(function() {
  return {
    value1: $(this).closest('.subscription').attr('data-subscription-id'), 
    value2: $(this).prop("checked")
  }
}).get();
```